# How to get all children of element in Katalon Studio

Tags: selenium, katalon-studio

I would like to find all elements within a root div element.

This is what I am doing:

```
@Keyword
public boolean verifySlotsOrder(int numOfSlots){
WebDriver driver = DriverFactory.getWebDriver()
WebElement slotsGrid =  driver.findElement(By.id('js-' + numOfSlots + '-grid'))
List<WebElement> children = slotsGrid.findElements(By.xpath('//*[@id="js-' + numOfSlots + '-slot"]'))
for(int i = 0; i < children.size; i++){
    KeywordUtil.logInfo(children[i].getText())
    }
 //return true or false once the slots order is validated
}
```

The problem with this code is that the method is not working how I assumed it would work. I the xpath would match a portion of each child WebElement's xpath and hence it would be added to my list. My id sequence for elements within the root div is:

js-numOfSlots-slot`<slotNum>`

where 1 <= slotNum <= numOfSlots

How can I properly generate a list of WebElements that follow this sequence of IDs and have a common parent WebElement. Also is this possible with Katalon TestObjects?

Here is the HTML. Note that I only want the immediate children, not all the decendents.

[image: HTML]

**Update:**

I am able to get all decedents of my root div by doing this:

```
List<WebElement> children = slotsGrid.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id, 'js-8-slot')]"))
```

and if I add `/div/div/div` at the end of my xpath, I get certain child elements, but I am still not sure how to properly get only the first layer child elements (immediat children).

Comment: can you please share the html for grid and slot  and any error that you received. At least the `id` for grid and slots

Comment: @supputuri I added the HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easier way of doing this is by using `("*")` which gives all the direct child elements of the context node.

**Implementation:**

```
WebDriver driver = DriverFactory.getWebDriver()
//get the parent element
WebElement slotsGrid =  driver.findElement(By.id('js-' + numOfSlots + '-grid'))
//use the parent element to get all the immediate children
List<WebElement> children = slotsGrid.findElements(By.xpath("*"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the xpath to get all the slot divs.

CSS:

```
div[id^='js-8-grid'] >div[id^='js-8-slot']
```

xpath:

```
//div[contains(@id,'js-8-slot') and parent::div[@id='js-8-grid']]
```

Implementation:

```
@Keyword
public boolean verifySlotsOrder(int numOfSlots){
    WebDriver driver = DriverFactory.getWebDriver()
    # don't need the grid here, we can access the slots directly
    List<WebElement> children = slotsGrid.findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(@id,'js-" +Integer.toString(numOfSlots) +"-slot') and parent::div[@id='js-" +Integer.toString(numOfSlots) +"-grid']]"))

    for(int i = 0; i < children.size; i++){
        KeywordUtil.logInfo(children[i].getText())
        }
}
```

Comment: im getting the following error: The string '//div[@id=js-8-grid']//div[contains(@id,'js-8-slot')]'' is not a valid XPath expression.

Comment: My bad, updated the answer. I have to use wratp xpath in `"` but I did it in `'`, that's why you got that error.

Comment: also, since you removed slotsGrid, I guess you should use driver.findElements, not slotsGrid.findElements, since slotsGrid doesn't exist anymore

Comment: this still gives me all the elements within the grid that have 'js-8-slot' somewhere in their ID, what I want is just the first layer of children, which are the 8 div elements directly contained in <div id = 'js-8-grid'</div>

Comment: ok, I thought you have the divs with that name in the first layer it self. let me update the answer.

Comment: I am still getting more than the immediate children, I only want the 8 immediate elements

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190308/discussion-between-zymeriath-and-supputuri).